# C# sendkeys not working properly on client side

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcpclient, sendkeys

I'm working on a tool in C# WinForms for sharing remote desktop via TCP.

What I have done till now is the desktop viewer and sending mouse clicks to the focused desktop sharing window. That works fine.

Now, Im working on send the keys pressed to the focused window, but it is not working properly for two cases:

> 1- when I keep pressed a key
>
> 2- when I start pressing keys fast

When I type slow, no issues..

In the **Viewer window** I have this constructor:

```
public ViewerWindow()
{    
        KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;

        InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Here is the handler that gets the pressed key and writes in the stream in order to pass it to the client:

```
public void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var keyPressed = e.KeyData.ToString();
            
    var key = string.Concat("keyboard", " ", keyPressed);
    //sending key here
    byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    client.GetStream().Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
}
```

And in the **Client** side inside the sream reading loop I have the below code to receive the key data and process it:

```
if (incomingData.Length > 7 && incomingData.Substring(0, 8) == "keyboard")
{
     string[] inf = incomingData.Split();

     if (inf.Length > 1)
     {
       Keyboard.SendKey(inf[1]);
     }
}
```

**Keyboard** is a static class with SendKey method that just has this code:

```
public static class Keyboard
{
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

        public static void SendKey(dynamic key)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait(key);
        }
}
```

However, when I keep pressed or type keys fasts I receive "keyboard" word, it seems that inf[1] it has "keyboard" word and I dont realize why ... any suggestion/idea to fix it?

I did it from scratch, but no idea if it could be a decent solution...

Any help or guiadance path will be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your TCP stream is buffering the send-data until it reaches a more suitable size?

Try [flushing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush?view=net-5.0) the stream after writing.

```cs
byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
var stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

Usually TCP connections collect multiple small data chunks into one big TCP packet to save network bandwidth. This behavior can be overwritten by setting the [`TcpClient.NoDelay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay?view=net-5.0) property to `true`, which will cause a flush after each call to `Write()`.